# Raise event in C# and catch in C++ MFC

Tags: c#, c++, event-handling, managed, raiseevent

I come from a .net background and I am fairly new to developing in C++. I am well used to events in C# and raising events when something meaningful happens. 
**What I'm not sure about it how to raise "an event" in C++ just when an event raised in C#.**

I know how to create Managed COM from c# code and use in c++ code.
Now I'm using a thread in c++ and check a variable that changes when c# trigger raised. but this solution is so bad...

> How to make event x(C#) and event y(C++ MFC) peer to peer so that when event x raised, event y raising too?

Comment: I maybe able to help from the 'receiving' (MFC) end but I'm not sure how "raising an event" works in `C#`! Can you give a brief explanation, like does this send a message to the queue?

Comment: @Adrian Imagine C# is listening to USB for joystick and when joystick button pressed, a C# event raised. I want that related event in C++ MFC raising too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Solved this challenge using "[SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage)" from C# to C++ or vice versa.
see: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5307/Use-WM-COPYDATA-to-send-data-to-from-C-and-C-Windo**